# You do not have permission to push to on Github. Would you like to create a fork and push to it instead

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code. I create a repository with one single file. But the file is not uploading with one warning stated as "You do not have permission to push to on Github. Would you like to create a fork and push to it instead"
Below a screenshot of the warning:
[image]

I have latest version of everything (git,VS Code)

Comment: Is https://github.com/sakibriyad2/pok your own repository? If yes, did you log in from vscode on your sakibriyad2 account?

Comment: Yes its my own repo and i did logged in to my account.

Comment: Same question, did you solve it?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and I managed to solve it by doing the following:

- In VScode sign out by clicking on the person icon on the left down on the
  screen and close VScode.
- After this go to your "Control Panel" in "Windows OS and search for "
  Credential Manager" and choose "Windows Credentials".
- Below you will see a list called "Generic Credentials", remove
  everything with the name "Git" and "Github". (this will remove your logins)

After all these steps, go back to VScode, login by clicking on the person Icon. When you click on publish, github will asks you to login in again and authorize. After this the error message was gone for me.

Comment: I am using a new git profile o nmy computer and this happend to me. Got it fixed with these steps, thanks.

Comment: Window 11 Control Panel shows Web Credential & Windows Credentials, I found it in Windows Credential the github credential and removed it. Thanks your answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

it can be caused because of your github account in VS-Code or because of your role in the project.In my case, I loged out in vs code and loged in again by right account.